# Successive over relaxation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, iteration

Here I have some python script, which solves the system of linear equations using Gauss-Seidel method:

```
import numpy as np

ITERATION_LIMIT = 1000

#system
A = np.array([[15., -4., -3., 8.],
          [-4., 10., -4., 2.],
          [-3., -4., 10., 2.],
          [8., 2., 2., 12.]
          ])
# vector b
b = np.array([2., -12., -4., 6.])

print("System of equations:")
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    row = ["{0:3g}*x{1}".format(A[i, j], j + 1) for j in range(A.shape[1])]
    print("[{0}] = [{1:3g}]".format(" + ".join(row), b[i]))

x = np.zeros_like(b)


for it_count in range(1, ITERATION_LIMIT):
    x_new = np.zeros_like(x)
    print("Iteration {0}: {1}".format(it_count, x))
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        s1 = np.dot(A[i, :i], x_new[:i])
        s2 = np.dot(A[i, i + 1:], x[i + 1:])
        x_new[i] = (b[i] - s1 - s2) / A[i, i]
    if np.allclose(x, x_new, rtol=1e-8):
        break
    x = x_new
```

What it outputs is:

```
Iteration 379: [-21.36409652 -22.09743    -19.9999946   21.75896845]
Iteration 380: [-21.36409676 -22.09743023 -19.99999481  21.75896868]
Iteration 381: [-21.36409698 -22.09743045 -19.99999501  21.7589689 ]
```

My task is to make a Successive Over Relaxation (SOR) method out of this, which uses omega values to decrease the number of iterations. If `omega = 1`, it becomes Gauss-Seidel method, `if < 1` - method of simple iterations, `> 1` and `< 2` - SOR. Obviously, with higher omega values the number of iterations should decrease. Here is an algorithm, that Wikipedia offers:

```
Inputs: A, b, omega
Output: phi (roots for linear equations)

Choose an initial guess phi to the solution
repeat until convergence
  for i from 1 until n do
    sigma <- 0
    for j from 1 until n do
      if j ≠ i then
        sigma <- sigma + A[i][j]*phi[j]
      end if
    end (j-loop)
    phi[i] = phi[i] + omega*((b[i] - sigma)/A[i][i]) - phi[i]
  end (i-loop)
  check if convergence is reached
end (repeat)
```

Does somebody have a working algorithm on python? It would be very good if you could make some comments to the code or help me how to change this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's an implementation based on that Wiki reference you provided.

```
import numpy as np

def sor_solver(A, b, omega, initial_guess, convergence_criteria):
  """
  This is an implementation of the pseduo-code provided in the Wikipedia article.
  Inputs:
    A: nxn numpy matrix
    b: n dimensional numpy vector
    omega: relaxation factor
    initial_guess: An initial solution guess for the solver to start with
  Returns:
    phi: solution vector of dimension n
  """
  phi = initial_guess[:]
  residual = np.linalg.norm(np.matmul(A, phi) - b) #Initial residual
  while residual > convergence_criteria:
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
      sigma = 0
      for j in range(A.shape[1]):
        if j != i:
          sigma += A[i][j] * phi[j]
      phi[i] = (1 - omega) * phi[i] + (omega / A[i][i]) * (b[i] - sigma)
    residual = np.linalg.norm(np.matmul(A, phi) - b)
    print('Residual: {0:10.6g}'.format(residual))
  return phi


#An example case that mirrors the one in the Wikipedia article
residual_convergence = 1e-8
omega = 0.5 #Relaxation factor

A = np.ones((4, 4))
A[0][0] = 4
A[0][1] = -1
A[0][2] = -6
A[0][3] = 0

A[1][0] = -5
A[1][1] = -4
A[1][2] = 10
A[1][3] = 8

A[2][0] = 0
A[2][1] = 9
A[2][2] = 4
A[2][3] = -2

A[3][0] = 1
A[3][1] = 0
A[3][2] = -7
A[3][3] = 5

b = np.ones(4)
b[0] = 2
b[1] = 21
b[2] = -12
b[3] = -6

initial_guess = np.zeros(4)

phi = sor_solver(A, b, omega, initial_guess, residual_convergence)
print(phi)
```

Answer (score 1):

For an extended answer on omega and its uses please refer to my other answer [SOR method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934158/what-is-the-significance-of-omega-in-successive-over-relaxation-rate-method/66769483#66769483) as what is quoted below is not accurate.

> Obviously, with higher omega values the number of iterations should decrease.

As for a working algorithm on SOR this is what I have computed, where best convergence is reached when the optimal omega is used. See section 3 on the paper [The Optimal Relaxation Parameter for the SOR Method Applied to
the Poisson Equation in Any Space Dimensions](https://userpages.umbc.edu/%7Egobbert/papers/YangGobbertAML2007.pdf)

```
def sor_method(A, b, omega, initial_guess, tolerance, max_iterations):
    t = time.time()
    x = np.zeros_like(b, dtype=np.double)
    

    iter1 = 0
    #Iterate
    for k in range(max_iterations):
        iter1 = iter1 + 1
        print ("The solution vector in iteration", iter1, "is:", x)    
        x_old  = x.copy()
        
        #Loop over rows
        for i in range(A.shape[0]):
            x[i] = x[i]*(1-omega) + (omega/A[i,i])*(b[i] - np.dot(A[i,:i], x[:i]) - np.dot(A[i,(i+1):], x_old[(i+1):])) 
            
        #Stop condition 
        #LnormInf corresponds to the absolute value of the greatest element of the vector.
        
        LnormInf = max(abs((x - x_old)))/max(abs(x_old)) 
        print ("The L infinity norm in iteration", iter1,"is:", LnormInf)
        if  LnormInf < tolerance:
            break
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print("Time elapsed is", elapsed)          
    return x
```