# Successive Over-relaxation Method and Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

I am writing a code for successive over-relaxation.

When I run the code, I get the following error:

x[i] = (1-w)*xold[i] + w*(d[i] + sum(C[i,:]*x)) # estimate new values

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np

# define function
# M is the coeff matrix; b is RHS matrix, x is the initial guesses
# tol is acceptable tolerance and Nmax = max. iterations

def sor(M,b,x,w,tol,Nmax):
    N = len(M)  # length of the coefficient matrix
    C = np.zeros((N,N)) # initialize iteration coeff matrix
    d = np.zeros(N) # initiation iteration RHS matrix
    # Create iteration matrix
    for i in np.arange(0,N,1):
        pvt = M[i,i]  # identify the pivot element
        C[i,:] = -M[i,:]/pvt # divide coefficient by pivot
        C[i,i] = 0 # element the pivot element
        d[i] = b[i]/pvt # divide RHS by Pivot element
        
    # Perform iterations
    res = 100 # create a high res so there is at least 1 iteration
    iter = 0 #initialize iteration
    xold = 1.0*x # initialize xold
    #res = np.linalg.norm(np.matmul(M,x) - b)
    # iterate when residual > tol or iter <= max iterations
    while(res > tol and iter <= Nmax):
        for i in np.arange(0,N,1):  # loop through all unknowns
            x[i] = (1-w)*xold[i] + w*(d[i] + sum(C[i,:]*x)) # estimate new values
        res = np.sum(np.abs(np.matmul(M,x) - b)) # compute res
        iter = iter + 1 # update residual
        xold = x
    return(x)

# Solve Example
Nmax = 100  # Max. Number of iteration
tol = 1e-03 # Absolute tolerance
M = [[1,1,1,0,0,0],
     [1,1,1,1,0,0],
     [1,1,1,1,1,0],
     [0,1,1,1,1,1],
     [0,0,1,1,1,1],
     [0,0,0,1,1,1]]
M = np.array(M) # Coefficient Matrix
b = np.array([1,1,0.5,1,0.5,1]) 
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0] 
y = np.array(y) # Initial Guesses
w = 1
X = sor(M,b,y,w,tol,Nmax) # Apply the function
print(X)
```

I am suppose to get the same answer as the built in function:
[ 1.   0.5 -0.5  0.  -0.5  1.5]

What am I missing that is causing this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting. I compared with the results obtained by the second answer to this SQ question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53251299/successive-over-relaxation and observed the same diverging behavior.

Comment: Why do you expect this to converge? M is not symmetric, or diagonally dominant.  Furthermore, your initial guess should be random. Compute the modulus of the largest eigenvalue of (D+wL)^-1(wU+(w-1)D). If it is not less than one, then SOR has no convergence guarantee.